# exe file does not open after extracting from an archive

Tags: zip, archiving, extract

I came across a very strange situation for me.

I transferred all of the files uploaded on a disk with medical scans (CAT scan) to my flash drive and then from the flash drive to my PC.
These are the files:
[image]

Then I archived all of the files (the whole folder) in order to send them to a friend, but I noticed that after extracting the .exe file no longer opens. Nothing happens after clicking on it. Whereas in the initial folder (which I transferred from my flash drive), the .exe opens a new window.

What's the reason and how can I fix that? Thank you!

Here's the content of the .inf file:

```
[autorun]
OPEN=autorun.exe /autorun
ICON=autorun.exe,0
SHELL\start\COMMAND=autorun.exe /autorun
SHELL\start=Start syngo fastView
```

Comment: What are the requirements for the application? If the application cannot be run, then the system you are trying to run it on, doesn't have something installed that is necesary.

Comment: @Ramhound. I noticed something else. When I try to open the .exe from inside the archive (using WinRar) the .exe opens (without even extracting). The problem is when I try to open it from the extracted folder. Then it does not open at all. I really don't know what's happening.

Comment: @Ramhound, I am running the .exe on the same PC (without and after extraction), so I don't think that's the problem.

Comment: @Ramhound, found something else. Before sending to an archive one of the .exe files which is maybe required for the application to run opens without any errors, but after extraction there is an error message: 'IVT toolkit for 3d could not be initialized'. Is this supposed to happen?

Comment: What is autorun supposed to start (look in autorun.inf)?

Comment: “Is this supposed to happen” - No; So install the toolkit

Comment: @JoepvanSteen, I edited the post and added the content of the autorun.inf file. I still don't understand what's happening and what happens after archiving the files that makes the .exe not executable after unarchiving.

Comment: "the .exe opens a new window" - with what?

Comment: @JoepvanSteen, this is what opens after running the .exe file from the initial folder which I transferred directly from the flash drive (without archiving): https://i.imgur.com/tT2kcjC.png. I want to say that I don't have this software installed on my PC and I suppose that it's in the folder syngo_fV.

Comment: and everything works normally from the USB flash drive?

Comment: BTW, see https://www.siemens-healthineers.com/digital-health-solutions/syngo-fastview for downloading syngo fastView, which might need to be installed. DICOM files eFilm (and eFilm Lite) can also be used to view them: https://efilm.software.informer.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ISTM it would be easier to extract the files to a folder. Then look in the syngo_fV folder and see if there's a file called syngo.exe which appears, is the viewer for your 'Dicom files'.

It may be that DICOMDIR is expected to be in the ROOT of the drive that's used to share the patient data and that this may be the issue when running from the archive or the extracted archive.

---

**EDIT:** It's this. If I extract everything to the ROOT of a drive, any drive really, it works as expected as soon as I run autorun.

So for example, if I pick drive x:, autorun.exe, autorun.inf, DICOM, DICOMDIR etc., all need to be in the root of the drive.

---

**EDIT 2:** I can make it work anywhere really, but then I have browse for the folder where the DIRCOMDIR file is.

So, click Patient > Patient Browser > click **...** button and browse for folder > then I clicked 'Add'.

[image]

---

[image]

Then double click autorun, it indicates it's processing DICOMDIR and finally

[image]

Comment: In the syngo_fV folder there are two executable files: 'autorun.exe' and 'syngo_fV.exe', but as I said in one of the comments after unarchiving they both does not open, and one gives an error message: 'IVT toolkit for 3d could not be initialized', which doesn't happen when executing from the initial folder.

Comment: I see, I missed that. Perhaps download the viewer straight from the source: https://www.siemens-healthineers.com/digital-health-solutions/syngo-fastview

Comment: But doesn't this mean if I want to send the archive to someone,  they would also have to download the viewer?

Comment: Also something interesting that I just noticed: 'autorun.exe' does not open even from the initial folder (as I call it), whereas 'syngo_fV.exe' opens the software from the picture I sent you (syngo). After unarchiving, 'syngo_fV.exe' does not open as well.

Comment: I just cannot grasp what's happening and it seems really strange to me.

Comment: I'd just sent the files and a URL to the viewer. Alternatively convert files to BMP, as they can be viewed with almost any image viewer.

Comment: @Katherine, there are more files needed to run syngo.  Recreate the archive by extracting **everything** on the disk and zipping that, keeping the folder structure. There must be other dependencies on the disk that you had not included.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik, I am not sure I got what you meant. I have a folder on my PC from which everything runs and works as it is supposed to. After archiving all of the files from the folder (on the same PC), and then unarchiving nothing works as expected.

Comment: @JoepvanSteen, the situation is the same even when I use the syngo_fV files from the link you sent me (and upload them to the syngo_fV folder).

Comment: @Katherine, when everything works, is the disk with the medical info still attached? There might be needed files on that disk. Also, *how* did you archive it? WinZip? Windows Zip? Another tool?

Comment: @DrMoishePippik, nope, the disk is not attached. Well, I tried everything. WinZip, WinRar, 7-zip.

Comment: autorun suggests everything is configured to run from a CD. I read in help: The CD or DVD version is given to you by the examining doctor. syngo fastView is on this CD and/or DVD together with the images of your examination. The application does not require any configuration: *Simply insert the CD or DVD* into the drive and view the images.

Comment: @JoepvanSteen, well, maybe it's really supposed to run only from a CD or DVD and that's why archiving the files makes things to not work properly.

Comment: @JoepvanSteen, you can download the archive from here if you feel like experimenting with it: https://we.tl/t-61nYivVBhY: I don't have issues with sharing them (of course not with malicious intent)

Comment: @JoepvanSteen, can you clarify for me what's your last edit supposed to mean, because I don't understand it. Where is the what supposed to be?

Comment: A VT scan: https://www.virustotal.com/gui/file/88c74e2de09a43438064821a650b5e109116b640237401da9d0b231b3755d660/detection.

Comment: I will edit my answer, wait.

Comment: @JoepvanSteen, But it works here for me: C:\Users\\[my username]\Documents\Archive. I don't know what you mean by 'root' drive.

Comment: @JoepvanSteen, and does not work here: C:\Users\\[username]\Desktop\Scanner.

Comment: @JoepvanSteen, can you clarify what do you mean by 'every root drive'?

Comment: The root of a drive is <drive letter>:\, so for example y:\

Comment: @JoepvanSteen, thanks! And how do you make it work everywhere?

Comment: like I said, I double click autorun and then browse for the folder which contains DIRCOMDIR file.

Comment: @JoepvanSteen, but didn't we arrive at the conclusion that it only works in the root of a drive?

Comment: autorun doesn't open everywhere for me

Comment: As I said it opens in here: C:\Users\\[my username]\Documents\Archive, which does not seem like a root of a drive to me.

Comment: For me, in root of drive, autorun opens viewer and patient. Next attempts in different locations I need to click patient > patient browser > select folder > Add but this may be due to the viewer remembering last location.

Comment: @JoepvanSteen, for me the exe file seems to only open when in the root of a drive.

Comment: @JoepvanSteen, it seems like you can run it from everywhere. I really don’t know what’s going on.

Comment: It may be some freak coincidence that you picked a folder where it does not want to run?

Comment: I think idea of the tool is it's sent to patient on either CD or USB flash drive. So then it will be in root anyway and can automatically find DIRCOMDIR which is an index file.

Comment: @JoepvanSteen, can it be because I named the folder in which I was working not using Latin letters. Let’s say ‘тест’?